# Why does JavaConversions._ do not take place for Buffer when java List is expected?

Tags: java, android, scala, scala-java-interop

I am using Scala in Android, and I want to convert scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer to Java.util.List. But it do not work out, can some help me out?

code:

```
package com.ssj.DoubanPipi.activity.fragment

import android.app.Fragment
import android.view.{View, LayoutInflater, ViewGroup}
import android.os.Bundle
import com.ssj.DoubanPipi.R
import android.widget.{ListView, SimpleAdapter}
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

/**
 * Created by shenshijun on 14-5-31.
 */
class MainFragment extends Fragment {
  override def onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup, savedInstanceState: Bundle) = {
    val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)
    val listView = (rootView findViewById R.id.fragment_list).asInstanceOf[ListView]
    val adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity, MainFragment.menu_list,
      R.layout.main_fragment_list, Array("text", "image"), Array(R.id.action, R.id.action_image))
    listView setAdapter adapter
    rootView
  }

  def onSign(view: View) {
  }
}

object MainFragment {
  val menu_list_text = Array(R.string.login, R.string.exit)
  val menu_list_image = Array(R.drawable.douban, R.drawable.exit)
  val menu_list = new ArrayBuffer[Map[String, Any]]()
  val len = menu_list_image.length
  for (index <- 0 until len) {
    val map = Map("text" -> menu_list_text(index), "image" -> menu_list_image(index))
    menu_list += map
  }
}
```

and the error message is the following:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]]
 required: java.util.List[_ <: java.util.Map[String, _]]
    val adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity, MainFragment.menu_list,
                                                              ^
```

Comment: Note, that you have to [explicitly] convert internal collection (scala map to java map) as well, which is probably the main reason why conversion do not kicks in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling .toList() on menu_list should do the job.

```
    MainFragment.menu_list.toList
```

edit:

In case you need to convert scala Map to java.util.Map also, this snippet should work:

<strike>menu_list.map(_.asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, Any]])</strike>

```
val javaMenuList: java.util.List[java.util.Map[String, Any]] = menu_list.map { map =>
  val javaMap: java.util.Map[String, Any] = map
  javaMap
}
```

Comment: Huh? Are you really sure that this snippet with brute force `asInstanceOf` **will** work? Have you tried this code by yourself? Why not simple type ascription?

Comment: Indeed it didn't work. I edited my post to include proper solution.

Comment: You don't need to be that wordy: `menu_list.map(x => x: java.util.Map[String, Any])`

Comment: I think you are right. And @om-nom-nom's right too.